# Установка ssl в докер контейнер на VPS для телеграм бота

Tags: docker, ssl, vps

Есть докер контейнер на сервере (VPS). В контейнере телеграм бот на C#, который требует наличие сертификата (SSL). Я попробовал установить сертификат на порт 80 с помощью апач, но он если и ставит SSL (существующий) то также занимает и сам порт, то есть докер контейнер я к нему не могу подключить. (Тогда зачем мне вообще этот ssl, если его нельзя использовать?)
Сервер заказан на reg.ru, из личного каб также попытался подключить тот самый сертификат уже к самому домену, но его установка тоже требует указать **свободный** порт, то есть докер опять же подключить не удастся.

**Вопрос**: Как подключить ssl к порту который слушает докер? Если это невозможно сделать, какой другой выход из этой ситуации?

Comment: Зачем докер слушает порт 80? Пусть он слушает какой-нибудь другой порт

Comment: SSL конфигурируйте в apache. Контейнер в докере запускайте на отдельном порту, в apache конфигурируйте [reverse proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) для приложения в докере. Profit